# DNS lookup failed when accesing myproject folder WAMP

Tags: php, apache, google-chrome, dns, wamp

->I have a folder called "School Management System" in www directory.
->When I launch localhost from chrome, and browse to folder under "Your Projects", I get the error:

This webpage is not available

```
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
Hide details
The server at school%20management%20system can't be found, because the DNS `lookup failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's name to` its Internet address. This error is most often caused by having no connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It can also be caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall preventing Google Chrome from accessing the network.
Did you mean [schoolmanagementsystem.net]?
Did you mean [schoolmanagementsystem.biz]?
Did you mean [schoolmanagementsystem.org]?
```

->My HOST file is currently as follows:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
# 102.54.94.97 rhino.acme.com # source server
# 38.25.63.10 x.acme.com # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
# 127.0.0.1 localhost
# ::1 localhost

127.0.0.1 localhost
```

->I also see the following intriguing message at every attempt in the apache_error_log file, which I can't seem to make much sense of:

```
[Tue May 05 07:52:22.891408 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 6176:tid 944] [client ::1:49838] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache24, referer: [localhost]
```

->netstat -aon | findstr :80 shows the following:

```
TCP 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 3688
TCP 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 6368
TCP 192.168.1.5:49604 104.75.84.24:80 CLOSE_WAIT 3864
TCP 192.168.1.5:49605 104.75.84.24:80 CLOSE_WAIT 3864
TCP 192.168.1.5:49606 104.75.84.24:80 CLOSE_WAIT 3864
TCP 192.168.1.5:49607 104.75.84.19:80 CLOSE_WAIT 3864
TCP 192.168.1.5:49608 104.75.84.24:80 CLOSE_WAIT 3864
TCP 192.168.1.5:49609 104.75.84.19:80 CLOSE_WAIT 3864
TCP 192.168.1.5:49610 104.75.84.24:80 CLOSE_WAIT 3864
TCP 192.168.1.5:50086 74.125.200.95:80 TIME_WAIT 0
TCP 192.168.1.5:50095 222.165.163.37:80 TIME_WAIT 0
TCP 192.168.1.5:50097 222.165.163.174:80 TIME_WAIT 0
TCP 192.168.1.5:50099 68.232.35.121:80 TIME_WAIT 0
TCP 192.168.1.5:50100 68.232.35.121:80 TIME_WAIT 0
TCP [::]:80 [::]:0 LISTENING 6368
TCP [::]:80 [::]:0 LISTENING 3688
```

PLease help me out here...:)

Comment: What is the full local URL you're trying to access?

Comment: I type localhost in chrome address address bar. The local URL should be C:\wamp\www\School Management System\

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have added some Virtual Hosts and uncommented this line in the `httpd.conf` file

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

The `conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` file contains some example code which you need to remove, this example code uses the default path for Apache of `C:/Apache24` which explains the **intriguing message**

So remove these 2 sample definitions from `conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and that error should go away.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Also [check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618) for details on how to get Virtual Hosts working properly.